# Get Layout Id from an already inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-inflate

Given a `View` object which has already been inflated by a layout, how can I retrieve the kind of layout it had been inflated yet? I want to check something like this:

```
convertView.getLayoutId() == R.layout.my_layout
```

If this does not work, do you think one possible way of tracking this is to  do as follows:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(getLayout(), null);
convertView.setTag(getLayout());
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is not recorded by the `View` system. If you want to track that, you will have to do so yourself. You could use `setTag()` and `getTag()`, for example.